# How to add a date picker to a website?

Tags: javascript, html, css, datepicker, rally

tI am using rally developer (www.rallydev.com) and would like to use a date picker to insert date and time.  However, I do not have the ability to upload any zip or images files into the website.  I am constrained to using just one html page with css and javascript on it.  In other words, I would like to find a way to use a date picker without having all the code for it with what I am developing.

Edit: Someone asked what the date picker will be used for. Obviously, the answer is to get the date and time.  I would like to use the date and time as an input to do further processing in my code.

Comment: There are plenty of JavaScript date-pickers. However, what will the picked date be used for? Closing as "not a real question".

Comment: jQuery UI: http://jqueryui.com. If you don't want to/can't host the library yourself you can link to Google's code library: https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AppSDK 1.0 unfortunately does not include a DatePicker component. I don't believe there are plans to add a DatePicker component to AppSDK 1.0. Rally's recommendation for AppSDK 1.0 developers has typically been to use a calendar/picker component from JQuery or similar. Of course, as you note, since you don't have the ability to host such a component on rally1, you would end up referencing javascript libs external to the host, which could wind up generating security warnings in many browsers.

Rally's preview of AppSDK2, which is built on ExtJS 4, includes a fully-incorporated DatePicker component:

https://rally1.rallydev.com/apps/2.0p2/doc/#!/api/Rally.ui.DateField

You may be interested in starting to develop your App on the AppSDK2 framework, as this will soon be Rally's preferred platform for Javascript development, once it's out of preview. You can find more information here:

https://rally1.rallydev.com/apps/2.0p2/doc/

Answer (score 0):

Here's some example, http://www.bitrepository.com/a-collection-of-free-javascript-date-pickers.html